# Error ORA-00933,PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored , PLS-00103 while running this in oracle, How to resolve it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting errors while running this code

```
Error report - 
ORA-06550: line 46, column 104:  
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended  
ORA-06550: line 43, column 11:  
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
ORA-06550: line 78, column 5:  
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:
```

I have a table named "STRUCTURE_TABLE" which looks like this

```
P_DATE    |  SS_CP  SS_OP    SS_HP   SS_LP    DIVS  AD_CP  AD_OP  AD_HP  AD_LP
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-08-10  | 27.15   26.5    29.4    26.25     null   0       0      0      0
11-08-10  | 26.9    27.45   27.9    26.275    null   0       0      0      0
12-08-10  | 26.3    26.7    26.7    26        0.98   0       0      0      0
13-08-10  | 26     26.025   26.575  25.75     null   0       0      0      0
```

And this is the code i am performing on it

```
declare
v_num integer := 1;
v_SS_CP number(8,5);
v_SS_OP number(8,5);
v_SS_HP number(8,5);
v_SS_LP number(8,5);
v_DIVSS number(8,5);
v_AD_CP number(8,5);
v_AD_OP number(8,5);
v_AD_HP number(8,5);
v_AD_LP number(8,5);
begin
for rec in (select P_DATE, SS_CP, SS_OP, SS_HP, SS_LP, DIVSS ,
                    AD_CP, AD_OP, AD_HP, AD_LP from STRUCTURE_TABLE order by P_DATE)
loop
   if(v_num = 1) then       
       update STRUCTURE_TABLE set AD_CP = SS_CP,
                                 AD_OP = SS_OP,
                                 AD_HP = SS_HP,
                                 AD_LP = SS_LP
       where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;     
   else
       if (rec.DIVSS is not null) then
          update STRUCTURE_TABLE set 
           AD_CP =
           v_AD_CP * (rec.SS_CP/ v_SS_CP) +
           rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_CP/v_SS_CP),
           
           AD_OP =
           v_AD_OP * (rec.SS_OP/ v_SS_OP) +
           rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_OP/v_SS_OP),
           
           AD_HP =
           v_AD_HP * (rec.SS_HP/ v_SS_HP) +
           rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_HP/v_SS_HP),
           
           AD_LP =
           v_AD_LP * (rec.SS_LP/ v_SS_LP) +
           rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_LP/v_SS_LP)
           
           where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
       else
          update STRUCTURE_TABLE set 
          
          AD_CP =
          v_AD_CP * (rec.SS_CP / v_SS_CP) where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE,
          
          AD_OP =
          v_AD_OP * (rec.SS_OP / v_SS_OP) where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE,
          
          AD_HP =
          v_AD_HP * (rec.SS_HP / v_SS_HP) where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE,
          
          AD_LP =
          v_AD_LP * (rec.SS_LP / v_SS_LP) where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE
        end if;
       
    end if;
      
       v_num:= v_num +1;
   
       v_SS_CP := rec.SS_CP;
       v_SS_OP := rec.SS_OP;
       v_SS_HP := rec.SS_HP;
       v_SS_LP := rec.SS_LP;
       
       v_DIVSS := rec.DIVSS;
       
       select AD_CP into v_AD_CP from STRUCTURE_TABLE
       where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
       select AD_OP into v_AD_OP from STRUCTURE_TABLE
       where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
       select AD_HP into v_AD_HP from STRUCTURE_TABLE
       where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
       select AD_LP into v_AD_LP from STRUCTURE_TABLE
       where P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
     
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm is great when looking for such errors.

Comment: We can not see your line's number.

Comment: not all UPDATE statements end with a ";" in your code.

Comment: This is very basic debugging. Comment out chunks of code and try to compile. Keep commenting out until it is successful. Then start uncommenting. If error, fix error then continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bunch of misplaced `WHERE` clauses.

This is OK (as far as that error is concerned; I can't test it without your tables, though).

```
DECLARE
   v_num    INTEGER := 1;
   v_SS_CP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_SS_OP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_SS_HP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_SS_LP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_DIVSS  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_AD_CP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_AD_OP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_AD_HP  NUMBER (8, 5);
   v_AD_LP  NUMBER (8, 5);
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (  SELECT P_DATE,
                        SS_CP,
                        SS_OP,
                        SS_HP,
                        SS_LP,
                        DIVSS,
                        AD_CP,
                        AD_OP,
                        AD_HP,
                        AD_LP
                   FROM STRUCTURE_TABLE
               ORDER BY P_DATE)
   LOOP
      IF (v_num = 1)
      THEN
         UPDATE STRUCTURE_TABLE
            SET AD_CP = SS_CP,
                AD_OP = SS_OP,
                AD_HP = SS_HP,
                AD_LP = SS_LP
          WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
      ELSE
         IF (rec.DIVSS IS NOT NULL)
         THEN
            UPDATE STRUCTURE_TABLE
               SET AD_CP =
                        v_AD_CP * (rec.SS_CP / v_SS_CP)
                      + rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_CP / v_SS_CP),
                   AD_OP =
                        v_AD_OP * (rec.SS_OP / v_SS_OP)
                      + rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_OP / v_SS_OP),
                   AD_HP =
                        v_AD_HP * (rec.SS_HP / v_SS_HP)
                      + rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_HP / v_SS_HP),
                   AD_LP =
                        v_AD_LP * (rec.SS_LP / v_SS_LP)
                      + rec.DIVSS * (v_AD_LP / v_SS_LP)
             WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
         ELSE
            UPDATE STRUCTURE_TABLE
               SET AD_CP = v_AD_CP * (rec.SS_CP / v_SS_CP),
                   AD_OP = v_AD_OP * (rec.SS_OP / v_SS_OP),
                   AD_HP = v_AD_HP * (rec.SS_HP / v_SS_HP),
                   AD_LP = v_AD_LP * (rec.SS_LP / v_SS_LP)
             WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
         END IF;
      END IF;

      v_num := v_num + 1;

      v_SS_CP := rec.SS_CP;
      v_SS_OP := rec.SS_OP;
      v_SS_HP := rec.SS_HP;
      v_SS_LP := rec.SS_LP;

      v_DIVSS := rec.DIVSS;

      SELECT AD_CP
        INTO v_AD_CP
        FROM STRUCTURE_TABLE
       WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;

      SELECT AD_OP
        INTO v_AD_OP
        FROM STRUCTURE_TABLE
       WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;

      SELECT AD_HP
        INTO v_AD_HP
        FROM STRUCTURE_TABLE
       WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;

      SELECT AD_LP
        INTO v_AD_LP
        FROM STRUCTURE_TABLE
       WHERE P_DATE = rec.P_DATE;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: you can test it on the snapshot of the table i have provided above named "STRUCTURE_TABLE"

Comment: Sure, if I were in a mood to type CREATE TABLE statement myself. I'm not. If you provided it, I could have used it.

Comment: I'll form next time, thank you. Worked smoothly.

Comment: _"you can test it on the snapshot of the table i have provided"_   No, we cannot test it on a snapshot.  We _can_ test on an actual table, created by executing a CREATE TABLE statement, which we could have copied  ---- if you had provided it.  Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)